# Multiple gallery with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I'm having an issue with some lightbox galleries.
I have to make multiples galleries in one page, but in each thumbnail it'll have multiples images from another div. I tried some Jquery lightbox, but it didnt have this feature. (fancy, feather, etc.)

a href="#gallery1"

a href="#gallery2"

...

div id="gallery1"

```
multiple images
multiple images
```

div id="gallery2"

```
multiple images
multiple images
```

The only "solution" i think about was to make some thumbnails with display none linking to the other images, but it's more than 200 images, and i think is a "bugged" solution...
There's any solution for that? Or Any specific Jquery can do it?

Thanks!

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: This was just a typo. The real problem is the multiple gallery without "thumbnailing" all images

Comment: I wonder why do you think that "it didnt have this feature". How you imagined it would work? Any decent lightbox script provides API to open gallery programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it does not matter if you have 2 or 200 images, you still need to somewhere store the data. Possible solutions (using fancyBox3):

1) Create links for all images, but make visible only the first one for each gallery. Something like this:

```
<p>
    <a href="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/357/31876784275_12286240d4_h.jpg" data-fancybox="images-preview">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/357/31876784275_fbc9696913_m.jpg" />
    </a>
</p>

<div style="display: none;">

  <a href="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/582/32752534825_4b35b2df81_o_d.jpg" data-fancybox="images-preview"
     data-thumb="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/582/32752534825_c25321a594_m_d.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2859/33395734202_522f9d8efd_k_d.jpg" data-fancybox="images-preview"
     data-thumb="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2859/33395734202_15a81c4ef3_m_d.jpg"></a>

</div>
```

As you can see, you do not need to create thumbnail image for each link, you can use `data-thumb` attribute instead. See the last example here - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/mqEMGX?editors=1000

2) Create custom click handler for your preview images that opens gallery programmatically, e.g., using `$.fancybox.open( [array of images], { your options });`. You can choose to store data in some variable or to use ajax to retrieve the list.